# C++ error on delete[] after iterating through pointer

Tags: c++

Environment:  Windows 7 pro x64, Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, Version 14.0.25424.00 Update 3

```
int testFunction()
{
    std::string _orig = "[188 80% (1/2)O:152]";
    std::string _orig2 = "[999 99% (1/1)O:999]";

    char *orig = NULL;
    char *orig2 = NULL;

    orig = new char[_orig.length() + 1];
    strcpy(orig, _orig.c_str());

    orig2 = new char[_orig2.length() + 1];
    strcpy(orig2, _orig2.c_str());

    *orig++;
    *orig2++;

    int a = atoi(orig);
    int b = atoi(orig2);

    delete[] orig;
    delete[] orig2;

    return 0;
}
```

Running the above code crashes with the "_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)" error.

If I don't iterate (*orig++  and *orig2++), then no issues.

So my question is, how can I iterate through the pointers and then when I'm done doing what I need to do with them, delete[] them correctly?

Comment: Why use `char` pointers at all? Use `std::string` throughout.

Comment: I would love to, but I need to use atoi(), which won't work on std::string

Comment: (1) Why do you need it? There are C++ equivalents. (2) You *can* actually pass the pointer inside a `std::string` to `atoi` just fine: `atoi(str.c_str())` works.

Comment: @Zyre of course it works with `std::string`. You must not have learned of `std::string::c_str()` yet.

Comment: @user2079303 Looking at the code, yeah, he did.

Comment: @WhozCraig oh right, so they did. Now I'm confused. Perhaps they have simply copy pasted the code, and don't yet grok what it actually does...

Comment: @user2079303 looking at the function name and the otherwise worthlessness of most of it, it appears to be an almost-completed attempted at a MCVE, so I expect a lot of things will look a little odd. Like the worthlessness of the indirection operator applied with `*orig++;` and `*orig2++;`. It happens when code gets stripped down. No worries.

Answer (score 2):

You did not delete the pointers you allocated!

`delete` must be called on the original memory address returned by `new`. Since you did `orig++`, you cant `delete` the address being pointed at!

Iterating can be done with an index, and using array subscription to dereference:

```
orig[i] = 'a';
```

Which is the same as doing this:

```
*(orig+i) = 'a';
```

Or you can get another pointer onto the same data, and modify this one.

```
char* pOrig = orig;
++pOrig;
```

Why did you write

```
*orig++; // why dereferencing?
```

Just `++` by itself would do the iteration.

Comment: Yes, the approach may very well be your second code block where you create a copy of the pointer and iterate through that, then delete the original.

Comment: The error comes from the delete, 
Iterating is easier with indices in my eyes, since you always now where u are atm.
Is your real code with a loop? Or did you really just go one step there?

Comment: As another comment mentioned, use std::string (if possible). There are conversion functions for it as well: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/  , e.g. stoi for string to integer conversion

Answer (score 2):

Avoid to use raw pointers. Your code can be simpler:

```
std::string orig = "[188 80% (1/2)O:152]";
std::string orig2 = "[999 99% (1/1)O:999]";

int a = atoi(orig.c_str() + 1);
int b = atoi(orig2.c_str() + 1);
```

Your mistake is that you try to delete the shifted pointers instead of the original pointers. As the result heap manager gets wrong allocated block information usually put before the allocated pointer and you got heap corruption.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I iterate through the pointers and then when I'm done doing what I need to do with them, delete[] them correctly?

Create a copy of the pointer:

```
char* orig = new char[size];
char* i = orig;
*i++ = 'a';
delete orig;
```

A perhaps more common idiom is to dereference a temporary:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    orig[i] = 'a';
```

---

> I would love to [use `std::string`], but I need to use atoi(), which won't work on std::string

You are mistaken. `atoi` works with `std::string` just fine. Simply use `std::string::c_str()` just like you did with `strcpy`. There is absolutely no reason to allocate a block of memory with `new`.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I was going to go too, but wasn't sure it was the best approach.  I'm glad you mentioned/confirmed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int testFunction()
{
    std::string _orig = "[188 80% (1/2)O:152]";

    int a = 0;
    for (std::string::iterator it = _orig.begin(); it != _orig.end(); ++it) 
    {
        if (isdigit((char)*it))
            a = (atoi(it._Ptr));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I got it.  Thanks for everyone who helped me come to this conclusion.  Staying with std::string was in fact the best approach.